# Download rstp stream in android

Tags: java, android, netty, rtsp

I am developing a application in android to stream and download video from IP camera over rtsp link.
I am able to show the rtsp video via the VideoView in android.
But i also want to download this video.
Unfortunately android doesn't support rtsp url to open UrlConnection.

For this I searched over and found netty to download rtsp streams, but i and new to this and i don't know how to use it to download rtsp streams.

Is there any other way to download rtsp links in android or in case of netty how to use it to download rtsp streams?

Code snippets will be usefull.

Thanks in advance.